# Convert a number to a list of integers

Tags: python, list, integer

How do I write the `magic` function below?

```
>>> num = 123
>>> lst = magic(num)
>>>
>>> print lst, type(lst)
[1, 2, 3], <type 'list'>
```

Comment: Magic.. nice way to ask question :).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
a = 123456
b = str(a)
c = []

for digit in b:
    c.append (int(digit))

print c
```

Answer (score 82):

You mean this?

```
num = 1234
lst = [int(i) for i in str(num)]
```

Answer (score 16):

You could do this:

```
>>> num = 123
>>> lst = map(int, str(num))
>>> lst, type(lst)
([1, 2, 3], <type 'list'>)
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3.0 map will return a generator, not a list.

Answer (score 11):

```
magic = lambda num: map(int, str(num))
```

then just do

```
magic(12345)
```

or

```
magic(someInt) #or whatever
```

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> def magic(num):
        digits = deque()
        while True:
            num,r = divmod(num,10)
            digits.appendleft(r)
            if num == 0:
                break
        return list(digits)

>>> magic(123)
[1, 2, 3]
```

According to my timings, this solution is considerably faster than the string method (`magic2`), even for smaller examples.

```
>>> def magic2(num):
        return [int(i) for i in str(num)]
```

**Timings:**

`magic`

```
>>> timeit.timeit(setup='from __main__ import magic', stmt='magic(123)')
1.3874572762508706
>>> timeit.timeit(setup='from __main__ import magic', stmt='magic(999999999)')
3.2624468999981673
```

`magic2`

```
>>> timeit.timeit(setup='from __main__ import magic2', stmt='magic2(123)')
3.693756106896217    
>>> timeit.timeit(setup='from __main__ import magic2', stmt='magic2(999999999)')
10.485281719412114
```

Comment: `map(int, str(n))` from the answer of @Wilbeibi is faster than both (tested on Python3)

Comment: @FelipeBuccioni `map` in python 3 will just create a generator, not a `list`. You need `list(map(int, str(n))`. `map(int, str(n))` does pretty much nothing by itself.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the word *list* as variable name! It is a name of python built in data type.

Also, please clarify your question. If you are looking for a way to create a one-member list, do the following:

```
a = 123
my_list = [a]
```

and "pythonizing" Cannonade's answer:

```
a = 123
my_list = [int(d) for d in str(a)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
num = map(int, list(str(num)))
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is named as magic, why not just use magic:

```
def magic(x):
    if x < 10:
        return [x]
    else:
        return magic(x//10) + [x%10]
```

Answer (score 1):

for python 3.x:

```
num = 1234
lst = list(map(int, str(num)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def convert_to_list(number):
    return list(map(lambda x: int(x), str(number)))

convert_to_list(1245)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use :

```
a= str (num)
lst = list(a)
```

Comment: that would return a list of characters, not *directly* integers